# Eventbrite API Check in

Tags: eventbrite

Is it possible for us to be able to check in and out users using the Eventbrite API?

I know I can get the barcode number and check it against the database but I was wondering if it is possible to do this.

Thanks -
Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work on Eventbrite's API and Platform team, so I can help you out here.

Unfortunately, there are currently no public APIs for updating a barcode on Eventbrite.

We're constantly working to improve our API functionality, so I'd love to still connect with you to gather requirements and answer other questions.

Comment: Any update on this? I would like to use the API to check in attendees from an iOS app.